# Can't Find JBoss-as-client-5.1.0.GA.jar to download

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss

I am looking for JBoss-as-client-5.1.0.GA.jar to download it and I can not seem to find it on the Maven Repository (this is what I find: [jboss-as-client](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.jbossas/jboss-as-client/5.1.0.GA)) When what I need is the files attribute in the description (one similar to [Files](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging/3.3.1.Final) )

Answer (score 0):

your version of dependencies is so old and you should update the version with below dependencies and update project, then file those jar into .m2 folder.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.jbossas</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-as-client</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0.20100721-M4</version>
</dependency>
```

and

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: thank you @MayankSharma for your answer. But I need that version for teaching purposes, I am not interested in a more recent version.

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.jbossas</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-as-client</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

Is this you want ?

Update : Hi , you can go to this page and see what all jar will be required as this jar  have dependencies on other jar too .

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.jbossas/jboss-as-client/5.1.0.GA

Once downlaoded check your  .m2 folder

**Repo in case Central Repo not work**
https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/jboss/jbossas/jboss-as-client/

Else you can try
 **direct download tool** 
https://jar-download.com/online-maven-download-tool.php

Comment: Thank you @gladiator for your answer. what I need is a link to download the jar and not the dependency.